# Working with canvas to display only the drawn image and not whole canvas

Tags: html, canvas, coordinates

With the plugin i found earlier on stackoverflow. Drawing has become smooth and nice. What i want is to only get the image part which i draw cropped from the canvas as an output and not the complete canvas. Can somebody help. 
This is the code i am using for my canvas now: http://jsfiddle.net/sVsZL/1/

```
function canvasDisplay() {
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
canvasImage=c.toDataURL("image/png");
document.getElementById("SSMySelectedImage").src=canvasImage;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer because the other one was completely off.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/sVsZL/7/)**

What you need essentially is to keep track of a bounding box. What I do is create an object that holds the min values and max values of where you've drawn. This enables you to keep track of how big the image is and where it begins/ends.

```
this.dim = {minX : 9999, minY : 9999, maxX : 0, maxY : 0};
```

Then I created a function that checks the bounds.

```
this.setDimensions = function(x,y){
        if(x < this.dim.minX){
            this.dim.minX = x;   
        }

        if(y < this.dim.minY){
             this.dim.minY = y;   
        }

        if(x > this.dim.maxX){
             this.dim.maxX= x;   
        }

        if(y > this.dim.maxY){
             this.dim.maxY = y;   
        }
    }
```

Make sure to check during clicking or moving.

```
    this.mousedown = function(ev) {
        tool.setDimensions(ev._x,ev._y);
    };

    this.mousemove = function(ev) {
            tool.setDimensions(ev._x,ev._y);
    };
```

And this is just a sample function that draws the portion to a new canvas that you could then save with `toDataUrl`

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var savedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                savedCtx = savedCanvas.getContext("2d"),
                minX = PEN.dim.minX,
                minY = PEN.dim.minY,
                maxX = PEN.dim.maxX,
                maxY = PEN.dim.maxY,
                width = maxX - minX,
                height = maxY - minY;

            savedCanvas.width = width;
            savedCanvas.height = height; 

           document.body.appendChild(savedCanvas);
           savedCtx.drawImage(canvas,minX,minY,width,height,0,0,width,height);  
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful code. But while practicing i found that some little part of image is been cut off from right and top. How do you increase the size of the capturing box?

Comment: @Lotkar : Well you look quite experienced. As i am new to coding. Can you help me drawing the same image with varying line width. In simple words i want the line width to vary from small to normal while dragging on the canvas. For making the drawing look little professional? Thanks